# jQuery Mobile refresh page after changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is there anyway to force a jQm page to reload once changePage is complete?

I have a number of pages dynamically loaded into an array. All of the pages that are being loaded are a part of a list, for example "20 mobile apps of 2011". Users will need to have the ability to swipe left and right to navigate the pages.

I've added the current code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cncpts/qMe6Z/2/

Notice how the URL's are being pulled from the array. From this i'm able to pull the next URL and the previous URL but I am only able to navigate one page forward and one back.

You can test the page here by clicking then swiping the mouse left or right: http://www.cncpts.me/complex/swipe/index.php

Any ideas on how to get the URL's to refresh while maintaining the native JQM transitions.

Comment: Do you mean you want to refresh pages the second time you view them? Or do you mean that you want to refresh pages are not currently being viewed?

Comment: I guess I don't need the browsers URL to change, i'm already doing this using the HTML5 history API. I need to update the URL's for next & previous. If you got to index2.php then swipe left, you'll get index3.php then try to swipe back you should get index2 but you get index.php. So it's storing the original page values, not new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [JQM pagaintion plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/)? Should be exactly what you are looking for.

If you want to change the URL you will have to set the *changehash* option to true in order for it to change

```
 $.mobile.changePage(next,{
      changeHash:true,
      reloadPage:true,
      dataUrl:next
      });
```

Here is the link to the [demo](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jqm-pagination/demo/)

Comment: If I wanted to use the pagination plugin how would initiate the pagination on swipe? The documentation doesn't clearly state how to use any of the options.

Comment: Also the changeHash would only work if I was implementing a single pages correct? I need the URL to change from index1.php to index2.php. When you enable the hashing, you get this index1.php#index2.php which doesn't get my anywhere. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. If you check the pagination demo (link above), on desktop you need to click left/right to change, while on touch-enabled devices you just swipe left/right and a change page will fire. The plugin is using separate pages (1/2/3/4.html) and the URL is updated, too. To set it up, you just need to add plugin and pagination triggers (links to your index2 and index3 page) and the rest is done by pagination.

Comment: This plugin works great for basic pages but once I load in the URL's from the array I'm only able to navigate one page.

Comment: Additionally the URL's are hashing.